# Clean Thesis template, change title font

Tags: fonts

I am using the wonderful Clean Thesis template, which works really nice but now I am stuggeling of changing the font of thesisTitle and thesisSubtitle to Helvitica. So far i insert `\fontseries{n}\fontfamily{phv}\selectfont` but where do I have to do it here?

```
\documentclass{scrreprt}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}    
\usepackage[english]{babel}     

\newcommand{\thesisTitle}{Effect of sugar on my hair, hand and ears}
\newcommand{\thesisSubtitle}{What happens if I eat to much of it?}
\newcommand{\thesisName}{Sugarcan and Coffeepot}
\newcommand{\thesisSubject}{Promising thing}
\newcommand{\thesisDate}{Today 2020}
\newcommand{\thesisVersion}{Second Version}

% Cover page content
\subject{\vspace{4.5cm} \thesisSubject}

\title{\thesisTitle}
\subtitle{\thesisSubtitle}
\author{\thesisName}
\date{\thesisDate}


\begin{document}
\maketitle                                  % making the title
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 1):

Found it myself. `\fontseries{n}\fontfamily{phv}\selectfont`has to go into control-thing without extra paranthesis {}.

```
\documentclass{scrreprt}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}    
\usepackage[english]{babel}     

\newcommand{\thesisTitle}{\huge\fontseries{n}\fontfamily{phv}\selectfont Effect of sugar blabla}
\newcommand{\thesisSubtitle}{\fontseries{n}\fontfamily{phv}\selectfont What happens if I eat to much of it?}
\newcommand{\thesisName}{Sugarcan and Coffeepot}
\newcommand{\thesisSubject}{Promising thing}
\newcommand{\thesisDate}{Today 2020}
\newcommand{\thesisVersion}{Second Version}


\subject{\vspace{4.5cm} \thesisSubject}

\title{\thesisTitle}
\subtitle{\thesisSubtitle}
\author{\thesisName}
\date{\thesisDate}

\begin{document}
\maketitle                                  % making the title
\end{document}
```